# Get Events from Facebook Page with php

Tags: php, facebook, api, httprequest

I'm trying to get the events from a Facebook page with a http request. It worked for the last 2 month, but now I'm getting this error:

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Here is my request:

```
$year_range = 2;

$since_date = date("d.m.Y", time());
$until_date = date('d.m.Y', strtotime('+' . $year_range . ' years'));

// unix timestamp years
$since_unix_timestamp = strtotime($since_date);
$until_unix_timestamp = strtotime($until_date);

$fields="id,name,description,location,venue,timezone,start_time";

$json_link = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $facebook_page_id . "/events/feed/?fields=" . $fields . "&access_token=" . $access_token . "&limit=200&since=" . $since_unix_timestamp ."&until=" . $until_unix_timestamp;
$json = file_get_contents($json_link);
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? I have no clue why this is not working anymore.

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Comment: Print out `$json_link` and go to the resulting URL. See what the error message is.

Comment: I'm getting this error message now: {
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) type must be one of the following values: attending, created, declined, maybe, not_replied",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
}

Comment: It appears the `events/feed` endpoint got deprecated. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/events

Comment: if I remove `/feed` it works again. thanks a lot!